# Flickering lights when appliances turn on

Tags: light

Recently our lights started flickering whenever a major appliance comes on.
Such as the furnace, dryer, fridge, washer...
All of them flicker only once, except for the washer. The lights flicker in tune to the washer agitating. It's really weird. They changed a few power poles on our street 2 years ago if it matters. I checked the 2 main wires coming in at the main breaker and got 121V and 116V. Then after checking every outlet in the house, about 12 of them have an open ground, but they all work. At the washer, the outlet had a reverse nuetral, which I fixed, but that didn't help with the flickering. I'm call the power company on Monday to come and check it out. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Do lights on both legs flicker when the washer is running, or only the ones that are on the same leg as the washer? Also, do any lights ever get *brighter* at all during this, or just dimmer?

Comment: They just get dimmer, then back to normal. I'll need to check where that leg is supplying and get back to you.... tx

Comment: Turned on all the lights in the house and they all flicker with the washer agitating or when the furnace comes on. So I guess the leg doesn't matter.... Could the washer having a reverse neutral damaged something?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it is a good idea to start with the power company in this matter.

Places I have seen this problem start from is higher resistance connections for the mains in the panel box, and higher resistance connections in the meter box, on the mains.

Most of the time, in my limited experience, it has been the mains into the power box.  You will want electrical gloves and appropriate tools.

Some of the time it is connections in the meter box.  Most frequently the fingers which grip contacts on the meter.

If you are not comfortable hunting this down, I suggest getting someone who is and has the right tools.  But if you power company investigates first, you will at least have assurance that the power available to you is stable.

Answer (score 0):

On the primary problem, I suspect the power company will solve it, but if not, I'd like to see some photos of your panel.

### That magic 8-ball tester, though...

Those things are a very fast way to make 3 measurements at once.  However, the label containing the *legends* is worse than useless. Those legends are optimized for pass-fail testing of new construction.  They are misleading for troubleshooting existing work.  Eearlier this week, an asker had one where the outer lights lit, and the legend said "hot-ground reverse", *not frickin' likely*.  I sketched it out and realized the lights were lighting at half power, and actually neutral was disconnected.  The asker quickly chased that down.

So the three lights are great.  The legend is trash.  Peel it off and give it a Viking funeral.  (Really, just never trust those labels again.)

And on that "hot-neutral reverse", okay, that actually is a plausible mistake, but **check it** - make sure white is on silver and black on brass. Make sure you didn't just *make it* wrong because the legend told you to.

Comment: So I called the power compnay on Monday and they had someone here in 20 minutes. It was a lineman, so he replaced the old wire and connectors from the pole to the house and that fixed the problem. Got 120.8 on both legs now and everything is working fine. Still going to hunt down my open grounds though.... Tx for all the help.